# Facebook sdk get city of residence

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to intergrate facebook login into my site, and I need to get that users City of Residence, using graph or FQL. If it doesn't exist, thats fine. I couldn't find it in the documentation...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query :

```
SELECT hometown_location from user where uid =me() or whomsoever you need
```

Above json response contains lots of stuff. :)

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

Make sure you are providing 'user_location' and 'friends_location' permissions for fetching yours/friend's location.